# How do I migrate an image attributes?

Tags: 8, migrations

I am migrating a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 using the Migrate API. So far, I have been able to do this without writing my own plugins.

How do I migrate additional information in an image field (e.g. the *alt* and *title* attributes)?

So far I have been using this, but it does not seem to work.

```
field_bild:
  plugin: iterator
  source: field_bild
  process:
    target_id:
      plugin: migration
      migration: d7_file
      source: fid
      alt: alt
      title: title
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the format I found working:

```
field_teaser_image/target_id:
  plugin: migration
  migration: attachment_image
  source: file_id
field_teaser_image/alt: file_alt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct format for 8.2 and up.

```
  field_bild:
    plugin: iterator
    source: field_bild
    process:
      target_id: fid
      alt: alt
      title: title
      width: width
      height: height
```

Comment: I think this might be a valuable answer, but could you please elaborate how to use this with the `migration` process plugin?

Comment: I'm little confused @Ambidex, the process plugin being used is the iterator