# How to migrate multilingual image alt fields from CSV?

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I'm migrating multilingual content to Drupal 8 from a group of CSV files, and I'm about 95% of the way there.  I have an image field attached to an article content type that shares the image among all translations, but the alt attribute is translatable. The remaining 5% problem is in configuring the migration to use a single common image file `fid` for all languages but a different `alt` text for other languages.

**articles.csv**

```
id,title_en,title_fr,body_en,body_fr,image,alt_en,alt_fr
1,Title 1,Titre 1,<p>English Body paragraph text 1</p>,<p>French Body paragraph text 1</p>,image1.jpg,Alt text English 1,Alt text French 1
2,Title 2,Titre 2,<p>English Body paragraph text 2</p>,<p>French Body paragraph text 1</p>,image2.jpg,Alt text English 2,Alt text French 2
3,Title 3,Titre 3,<p>English Body paragraph text 3</p>,<p>French Body paragraph text 1</p>,image3.jpg,Alt text English 3,Alt text French 3
```

**images.csv**

```
image
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

### English Content Migration w/ Image & Alt text

My default English content migration works great with images being imported and attached to nodes.

**migrate_plus.migration.articles_images.yml**

```
id: articles_images
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - file
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: default
label: Article Images
source:
  constants:
    source_base_path: ../import/images
    uri_file: 'public://images/imported'
  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: ../import/images.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - image
  column_names:
    -
      image: Image
process:
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - image
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri_file:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/uri_file
        - image
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  filename:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: image
    -
      plugin: get
      source: image
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@source_full_path'
      - '@uri_file'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

**migrate_plus.migration.articles_en.yml**

```
id: articles_en
status: true
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: default
label: Articles
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: ../import/articles.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    -
      id: Id
    -
      title_en: 'Title EN'
    -
      title_fr: 'Titre FR'
    -
      body_en: 'Text EN'
    -
      body_fr: 'Texte FR'
    -
      image: Image
    -
      alt_en: 'Alt Text EN'
    -
      alt_fr: 'Alt Text FR'
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
  title: title_en
  body/value: body_en
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: basic_html
  field_image/target_id:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: image
    - 
      plugin: migration
      migration: articles_images
      source: image
      no_stub: true
  field_image/alt:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: image
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: alt_en
    -
      plugin: get
      source: alt_en
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  optional:
    - articles_images
```

### French Content Translation w/ different alt text

However, every configuration I try to make the  foreign language translations use the same FID but a *different* alt text fails.

**migrate_plus.migration.articles_fr.yml**

```
id: articles_fr
status: true
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: default
label: Articles French
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: ../import/articles.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    -
      id: Id
    -
      title_en: 'Title EN'
    -
      title_fr: 'Titre FR'
    -
      body_en: 'Text EN'
    -
      body_fr: 'Texte FR'
    -
      image: Image
    -
      alt_en: 'Alt Text EN'
    -
      alt_fr: 'Alt Text FR'
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
  nid:
    plugin: migration
    source: id
    migration: articles_en
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: fr
  title:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: title_fr
    -
      plugin: get
      source: title_fr
      language: fr
  body/value:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: body_fr
    -
      plugin: get
      source: body_fr
      language: fr
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: basic_html
  field_image/target_id:
    plugin: migration
    migration: articles_images
    source: image
    language: fr
  field_image/alt:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: image
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: alt_fr
    -
      plugin: get
      source: alt_fr
      language: fr
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  translations: true
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - articles_en
  optional: {  }
```

Running the French data migration, I get an error message.

```
InvalidArgumentException: Invalid translation language (und) specified.
in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslation() (line 745 of
web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).
Invalid translation language (und) specified.
(web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:770)
```

**French Content Translation w/ basic image sharing**

I've also tried processing just the field_image to copy over to the the foreign translations, but it gives the same error:

```
field_image:
  plugin: migration
  migration: articles_images
  source: image
  no_stub: true
```

Adding or leaving off the `language: fr` parameter from any of the field processors seems to make no difference -- the error is the same either way.

### The intended resulting data structure

Inspecting a `field_image` attached to a node that was created and translated manually through Drupal UI at `node/X/devel` shows the following structure:

```
[field_image] => array(
  [x-default] => array(
    [0] => array(
      [target_id] => 123
      [alt] => English Alt text
      [title] => 
      [width] => 480
      [height] => 360
    )
  )
  [fr] => array(
    [0] => array(
      [target_id] => 123
      [alt] => French alt text.
      [title] => 
      [width] => 480
      [height] => 360
    )
  )
)
```

### Additional Resources

These blog posts and example repositories have been helpful in the lead up to where I'm currently stuck:

- https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/lucas-hedding/migrating-using-csv
- https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/ada-hernandez/how-migrate-images-drupal-8-using-csv-source
- https://github.com/heddn/d8_custom_migrate
- https://github.com/wunderkraut/migrate_source_example/tree/8.2.x/modules/migrate_source_example_csv
- https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2017/01/05/drupal-8-multilingual-content.html
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220424/3167
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2733431
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2677202

Comment: Can you post a few lines of your cvs file? Just to test the migrations

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer complete CSV and yaml files have been added.

Comment: `migration: article_images` looks like a typo. That should be `migration: articles_images`, right?

Comment: thanks, typo fixed.  (sadly had nothing to do with the bug, just a copy/paste error in my generalizations from project-specific code names to this)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I've figured this out. You need to define the 'content_translation_source' property on the translated node, so that Drupal knows what language it's coming from.

Eg:

**migrate_plus.migration.articles_fr.yml**

```
process:
  #...
  content_translation_source:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: en
  #...
```

(Be sure to substitute the value `en`  for whatever language you've first imported content -- the example in the OP uses English, but this might be anything).

---

I was asked how I figured this out:

I'm the guy who got multilingual migrations into D8 core, so I do know a bit about the matter :)

In this case, I used xdebug and put a breakpoint where the exception was thrown (ContentEntityBase.php line 745). It looked weird that it was using 'und' as the langcode, rather than 'en'—so I looked up the call stack to see where that was coming from. It turns out to be from content_translation_entity_presave(), which runs:

$source_langcode = !$entity->original->hasTranslation($langcode) ? $manager->getTranslationMetadata($entity)->getSource() : NULL;

In this case `$manager->getTranslationMetadata($entity)->getSource()` is basically equivalent to `$entity->content_translation_source->value`.

I wondered, why would that yield 'und'? I checked what happens when I translate an entity in the browser, and in that case it gives me 'en'. Something must be setting the source language! Indeed, ContentTranslationHandler::entityFormEntityBuild() calls setSource() when we're translating in-browser.

So, I figured I would just replicate that behaviour in the migration, by setting content_translation_source in the process. This also explains why D6 -> D8 migration of translations work, since d6_node_translation.yml has content_translation_source in the process.

Comment: Thanks @vasi and welcome to Stack Exchange.  I've edited your comment to make the example a bit more clear (their flavor of markdown doesn't format code blocks well with three backticks). I will test this out ASAP and confirm to see if it works.

Comment: Oops. I've deleted my previous comment, due to my own error (my source language wasn't "en".  This `content_translation_source` fixed the issue!  Amazing work Vasi++ THANK YOU.

Comment: I'm curious how you figured this out?

Comment: I added some debugging explanation to the answer, I hope that's helpful.

Comment: @vasi when migrating  paragraphs, does this solution apply? Or is it trictly a node thing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @vasi, Those who are still facing the issue can update the translation script like:

```
process:
  content_translation_source: source_langcode
```

where source_code is the default nodes language_code